# Docker Container is running but the program inside the docker stops abruptly

Tags: python, dockerfile, data-science

I have a Python Program which runs perfectly as standalone program
Time Taken - 5 days

I dockerize the program and execute it with 10% of dataset 
docker runs and the program executes successfully

When i use full dataset(108K records) and build and run the new docker
The Docker starts running for 4 hours and logs the steps perfectly

After 4 hours no logging is done 
when i inspect using htop no resource is being used
[htop image - sys resource use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e72B.png)

for docker stats it is not using any resource
[docker stats image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbu7j.png)

For docker ps it shows the image is running
[docker ps image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vu0Ci.png)

Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong

Is docker has any limits to running a program or logging data

Comment: How are you running the docker container? What command are you using? Is it on a server or local system?

Comment: docker run -d image_name
It is running on server - Amazon Linux - EC2

Answer (score 0):

Are you running docker directly on linux or are you using OSX/Windows for it, if so, you might be hitting memory limits.

If running on the cloud (AWS...) check that the machine has no expiry or something like that. I recommend trying to run that locally first.

Comment: I am running on amazon linux - EC2 Instance
Ec2 specs --> 40 vCPU and 160 GB RAM


Success Scenario: 
The program ran in a VM 32 GB RAM 4 vCPU

Comment: it uses tpot algorithm
it leverages all cores in the instance